# How to compare CBUUID objects in Xamarin.ios app

Tags: c#, ios7, xamarin.ios, uuid, core-bluetooth

I am developing a Xamarin.iOS Bluetooth enabled app  and i have some hurdles which i need to overcome. I am trying to make a connection from C# iOS app to peripheral device; I can connect successfully to the device but after discovering services and characteristics of the device, I need to catch particular service so that i can further use it for different purposes.

Now, the issue is how can i catch particular service from list of services in the cb peripheral object. Each service is identified by `CBUUID` object and i already know the `CBUUID` object that the device is returning, but i am not sure how can i compare them so that i know i catch the appropriate service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 7.1 (or later) then you can compare the `System.String` `Uuid` property of `CFUUID`. That's the easiest way. E.g.

```
if (cbuuid1.Uuid == cbuuid2.Uuid)
    Console.WriteLine ("Equal");
else
    Console.WriteLine ("Different");
```

Otherwise (iOS 7.0 and earlier) you'll need to compare the `NSData` `Data` properties of `CFUUID`. First compare their length and, if equal, compare each byte inside them. E.g.

```
bool equal = false;
using (var d1 = cbuuid1.Data)
using (var d2 = cbuuid2.Data) {
    if (d1.Lenght == d2.Length) {
        for (int i=0; i < d1.Lenght; i++) {
            if (d1 [i] != d2 [i]) {
                equal = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine (equal ? "Equal" : "Different");
```

Comment: Thanks @poupou , It made me clear pretty much. Yes, i am targeting iOS 7.1 and i will try this out.

Comment: Hi Poupou, it worked perfectly fine. But, just got stuck on another part. I am trying to scan a device every time when i test it. And. I am not sure how to utilize the retrieve know peripherals event of cb central manager class Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: No, I never really worked with bluetooth devices. You better ask a new question so more people will be able to see it and help you.

Comment: Ok, never mind i have just looked at the core bluetooth documentation and got my answer. Thanks